# Google Maps with markers only

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-markers

I'm using Google Maps at the moment to visualize a graph, with nodes being markers and edges being polylines. The nodes are actual places with WGS coordinates. Now that I would like to add more information to this graph, the map background becomes a bit superfluous.

Is there a way to eliminate the map background and just keep the markers?

Many thanks,
Cedric

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a Custom Map Type with empty tiles:

[documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/maptypes#BaseMapTypes)

[example from the documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/maptype-base) (remove the numbers).